# Поиск сайтов с определенным содержимым

Tags: html, парсер

Есть задача найти сайты, имеющие внешнюю ссылку на определенный сайт. Как можно автоматизировать этот процесс?

Comment: Зарегистрировать у поисковиков в инструментах вебмастера, они сами найдут.

Comment: это не мой сайт